# How can Python nosetests (version 1.1.2) be set to show logging output?

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging, nose, nosetests

I have a set of unit tests that all feature logging output at various logging levels. When I run these unit tests individually or via a shell script, all logging is shown. When I run these unit tests using `nosetests` of Python [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), I don't see the logging output. How can I show the logging?

The version of `nose` I am using is 1.1.2 (and I cannot change this):

```
-bash-4.1$ pip freeze | grep nose 
nose==1.1.2
```

Currently, I am running `nosetests` using a command like the following:

```
nosetests --verbosity=2 *.py
```

When I try to use the option `--logging-level=INFO`, I run into difficulty:

```
Usage: nosetests [options]

nosetests: error: no such option: --logging-level
```

Comment: First thing to try is to use `-s` option, which allows printing stdout and stderr output.

Comment: Ah, this is a step in the right direction. Thanks! Now I can see the logging at the INFO level. Would you happen to know how to show logging at other levels (e.g. DEBUG)?

Comment: It looks like --logging-level was added in 1.2.0. If you really can't upgrade nose (which I recommend, 1.1.2 is three years old at this point), you'll have to write a wrapper or plugin and set the log level that way.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about a feature added in `1.2.0` and saying that you cannot upgrade.

So unless you are into patching your obsolete version by backporting this feature, the answer is **find a way to upgrade**.